# My reset.css does not work on my id="root" tag with react js

Tags: css, reactjs, root

I tried to apply reset.module.css to my react project.

```
html,body,#root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

import CSS file above in index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./css/reset.module.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And here is index.html that you have known.

```
<body> 
   <div id="root" > </> 
</body>
```

I'm curious why CSS only doesn't work on div id="root".

Could you help me with what causes this problem?

Comment: Please try this way:```#root, #root > div {height: 100%;}```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But it also doesn't work. : (  my App.js component does not have any div tags. It consists of a Router like below. Is it possible to affect this problem? 

return (
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.BASE_URL}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<AboutMe />} />

Comment: Is your CSS file getting imported? And is there a special reason for not closing your div element with a </div>?

Comment: There was no Html syntax error on the div I wrote above. Because  I wrote by myself to show you the structure's shape in my project, there are some typos.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn a little more about how normal stylesheet and modules stylesheet work.

To learn visit: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Solution: Rename your reset.module.css as reset.css and import accordingly.

Comment: Awesome! Solved!  Thanks to you. I think I know what to do next.